# Byobu F1 help closes current window

Tags: byobu

Somehow when I press F1 Byobu opens its help page in the current window. After closing the help page the window is closed. I am running Arch Linux.

While working with vim I often hit F1 by accident instead of ESC and my vim session is closed. This is so frustrating..

On my server(Ubuntu 18.04) the byobu help page is opened in a new window when I press F1.

According to the help page the F1 key is * Used by X11 *.

How can sort this out/change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be worked around by unbinding the F1 key in the config. Just add

`unbind-key -n F1`

to `$HOME/.byobu/keybindings.tmux` (assuming you are using tmux as backend)